# Bioprobit - the covariance matrix of the Beta’s

Tags: stata

I am comparing weights of credit rating determinants across Moody's and S&P's. 
The goal of doing the bioprobit analysis is then to do a test whether the beta coefficients are the same between Moody's and S&P.
I wanna do this based on a Wald test, but I need the covariance matrix of the Beta’s.  Could you please help me with the code for Stata how to get the covariance matrix??

Variables entering the model are S&Prat Mrat GDP Inflation Ratio etc

Thanks in advance

Comment: You give precisely no detailed code, but seem to expect that your question is transparent and we can work out detailed code for you. Why is that? Are you using the `bioprobit` command from SSC? It comes with a help file, but there appears to be no other literature. Whether or not that is true, adding detail of code and results to your question is likely to increase the chance of a useful answer, at present near zero. All that said, did you try `ereturn list` to see what your command leaves behind in memory?

Answer (score 2):

Based on `@Nick Cox:`

Example from `Stata data` (you need to install `bioprobit` which is user written command)

```
sysuse auto 
bioprobit headroom foreign price length mpg turn


. bioprobit headroom foreign price length mpg turn

group(forei |
        gn) |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          1 |         52       70.27       70.27
          2 |         22       29.73      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |         74      100.00

initial:       log likelihood =  -148.5818
rescale:       log likelihood =  -148.5818
rescale eq:    log likelihood = -147.44136
Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -147.44136  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -147.43958  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -147.43958  

Bivariate ordered probit regression               Number of obs   =         74
                                                  Wald chi2(4)    =      22.61
Log likelihood = -147.43958                       Prob > chi2     =     0.0002

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
headroom     |
       price |  -.0000664   .0000478    -1.39   0.164      -.00016    .0000272
      length |   .0347597    .013096     2.65   0.008      .009092    .0604274
         mpg |  -.0118916   .0354387    -0.34   0.737    -.0813502    .0575669
        turn |  -.0333833   .0554614    -0.60   0.547    -.1420857    .0753191
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
foreign      |
       price |   .0003981   .0001485     2.68   0.007     .0001071    .0006892
      length |  -.0585548   .0284639    -2.06   0.040     -.114343   -.0027666
         mpg |  -.0306867   .0543826    -0.56   0.573    -.1372745    .0759012
        turn |  -.3471526   .1321667    -2.63   0.009    -.6061946   -.0881106
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
athrho       |
       _cons |    .053797   .3131717     0.17   0.864    -.5600082    .6676022
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      /cut11 |    2.72507   2.451108                     -2.079014    7.529154
      /cut12 |   3.640296   2.445186                     -1.152181    8.432772
      /cut13 |   4.227321   2.443236                      -.561334    9.015975
      /cut14 |   4.792874   2.452694                     -.0143182    9.600067
      /cut15 |   5.586825   2.480339                      .7254488     10.4482
      /cut16 |   6.381491   2.505192                      1.471404    11.29158
      /cut17 |   7.145783   2.529663                      2.187735    12.10383
      /cut21 |  -21.05768    6.50279                     -33.80292   -8.312449
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         rho |   .0537452   .3122671                     -.5079835    .5834004
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LR test of indep. eqns. :            chi2(1) =     0.03   Prob > chi2 = 0.8636


# results that are in `Stata's memory` 




ereturn list

scalars:
                 e(rc) =  0
                 e(ll) =  -147.4395814769408
          e(converged) =  1
               e(rank) =  17
                  e(k) =  17
               e(k_eq) =  11
               e(k_dv) =  2
                 e(ic) =  2
                  e(N) =  74
         e(k_eq_model) =  1
               e(df_m) =  4
               e(chi2) =  22.60944901065799
                  e(p) =  .0001515278365065
               e(ll_0) =  -147.4543291018424
              e(k_aux) =  8
             e(chi2_c) =  .0294952498030625
                e(p_c) =  .8636405133599019

macros:
            e(chi2_ct) : "LR"
             e(depvar) : "headroom foreign"
            e(predict) : "bioprobit_p"
                e(cmd) : "bioprobit"
           e(chi2type) : "Wald"
                e(vce) : "oim"
                e(opt) : "ml"
              e(title) : "Bivariate ordered probit regression"
          e(ml_method) : "d2"
               e(user) : "bioprobit_d2"
           e(crittype) : "log likelihood"
          e(technique) : "nr"
         e(properties) : "b V"

matrices:
                  e(b) :  1 x 17
                  e(V) :  17 x 17
           e(gradient) :  1 x 17
               e(ilog) :  1 x 20

functions:
             e(sample)   

#You need to use mat list e(V) to display the variance covariance matrix

mat list e(V)

symmetric e(V)[17,17]
                   headroom:   headroom:   headroom:   headroom:    foreign:    foreign:    foreign:    foreign:
                      price      length         mpg        turn       price      length         mpg        turn
 headroom:price   2.280e-09
headroom:length  -1.431e-07   .00017151
   headroom:mpg   3.991e-07   .00018914    .0012559
  headroom:turn   4.426e-07  -.00050302   .00027186   .00307597
  foreign:price   1.124e-10  -4.999e-09   2.093e-08   2.079e-08   2.205e-08
 foreign:length  -5.846e-09   8.021e-06   9.950e-06   -.0000249  -2.087e-06   .00081019
    foreign:mpg   1.712e-08   .00001035   .00006387   .00001352   1.254e-06    .0006546   .00295746
   foreign:turn   1.145e-08  -.00002418   .00001022   .00015562  -.00001083  -.00028103   -.0001411   .01746805
   athrho:_cons   2.360e-07  -.00004531    .0000684   .00005575  -2.010e-06   .00043717  -.00147713  -.00449239
    cut11:_cons    .0000134   .01507955   .07578798   .03653671   1.039e-06   .00068972   .00401168   .00211706
    cut12:_cons   .00001374   .01514192   .07570527   .03630636   9.488e-07    .0007133   .00386727   .00165474
    cut13:_cons   .00001393   .01520261   .07550433   .03603257   9.668e-07    .0007088   .00386171   .00165557
    cut14:_cons   .00001363   .01539981   .07532214   .03582323   1.042e-06   .00068687   .00392914   .00189195
    cut15:_cons   .00001264   .01584186   .07541396   .03541453   1.101e-06   .00068091    .0040106   .00209853
    cut16:_cons   .00001148   .01611862   .07562328   .03535426   1.052e-06   .00069849   .00401805   .00206701
    cut17:_cons   .00001055   .01602514   .07547739   .03620485   9.866e-07   .00069868   .00399718   .00207143
    cut21:_cons   4.412e-07   .00073781   .00377201   .00190456  -.00058242   .13231539   .18778679   .51179829

                     athrho:      cut11:      cut12:      cut13:      cut14:      cut15:      cut16:      cut17:
                      _cons       _cons       _cons       _cons       _cons       _cons       _cons       _cons
   athrho:_cons   .09807649
    cut11:_cons   -.0064343   6.0079319
    cut12:_cons   .00229188   5.9652808   5.9789347
    cut13:_cons   .00187855   5.9546524   5.9639617   5.9694026
    cut14:_cons  -.00310632   5.9724552   5.9793328   5.9820512   6.0157096
    cut15:_cons  -.00783593   6.0300908     6.03522   6.0360956   6.0667389   6.1520838
    cut16:_cons  -.00756313   6.0745198   6.0789515   6.0788816   6.1081885   6.1880183    6.275988
    cut17:_cons  -.00673882   6.0811477   6.0851101   6.0844209   6.1128719   6.1897756   6.2679698   6.3991936
    cut21:_cons  -.13478036   .30582954   .28918756   .28844026   .29527602   .30401845   .30575462   .30503648

                      cut21:
                      _cons
    cut21:_cons   42.286275

# If you want to use variance covariance matrix of first four variables

mat kk=e(V)
mat kkk=kk[1..4,1..4]
mat list kkk

symmetric kkk[4,4]
                   headroom:   headroom:   headroom:   headroom:
                      price      length         mpg        turn
 headroom:price   2.280e-09
headroom:length  -1.431e-07   .00017151
   headroom:mpg   3.991e-07   .00018914    .0012559
  headroom:turn   4.426e-07  -.00050302   .00027186   .00307597
```

Comment: Likely to be very helpful to poster. Small correction of terminology: `bioprobit` is in Stata terms a user-written command, not a function.